# How to move any element (rects, images etc) on a canvas without deletinng all content

Tags: javascript, html

How I can move a element inside canvas without deleting all inside content with `context.clearRect()`?

For example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/silhouette-forest-background_8589-304.jpg';
image.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
  window.onload = function()
  {
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillRect(20, 300, 60, 60);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to move the red square without deleting the background. I think I can make this using `save` and `restore`, but I don't know how to do it... Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is drawing the rectangle and the background in the same canvas crucial? If not, I'd rather suggest you to separate the background and the layer containing rectangles to different but overlapped canvases.

Comment: @SdtElectronics i think i got the ideia, but how i can do this? Multiple canvas with different z-index?

Comment: Actually plain canvas is not suitable for interactions involving drag and drop since it doesn't save the state of objects drawn. If you don't mind including extra libraries, [fabricjs](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js) is a nice choice. Or if you don't need canvas specific features, use a `<div>` to represent the rectangle.

Comment: My objective is making a game with this. I already maked some ones, but i want to know if theres a way to make it, if theres will help a lot.